# Itertools.count Python

Tags: python, count, python-itertools

I am taking a [datacamp tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-iterator-tutorial) and am wondering if someone could please explain why this code prints out the ODD numbers up to 11? I was thinking each next() call steps through the sequence, but if I follow this thought, the first print should be the number 2 (count(0) goes to count(1) when it first hits the while and then when it prints, it should go to count(2).

TIA.

```
from itertools import count
sequence = count(start=0, step=1)
while(next(sequence) <= 10):
    print(next(sequence))
```

1
3
5
7
9
11

Comment: No, the very first call to `next` yields 0, not 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`next(sequence)`, as the name says, will get the next element in the provided sequence.

Once an element is obtained, a further call to `next(sequence)` will simply yield the *next* number after that one (providing we are reusing the same `sequence`).

```
>>> sequence = count(start=0, step=1)
>>> next(sequence)
0
>>> next(sequence)
1
>>> next(sequence)
2
```

Note that, if you re-generate the sequence, you'll start over:

```
>>> sequence = count(start=0, step=1)
>>> next(sequence)
0
>>> next(sequence)
1
>>> sequence = count(start=0, step=1)
>>> next(sequence)
0
```

---

In your code you are calling `next(sequence)` on the while condition, and then `next(sequence)` for the `print` function, so both values will be different. Basically, as the `next` calls are alternated between the `while` and the `print` you'll see that the `print` will print out the odd values.

You can see a similar behavior if you add one more `next`:

```
from itertools import count
sequence = count(start=0, step=1)
while(next(sequence) <= 10):
    noop = next(sequence)
    print(next(sequence))
```

This will print out `2 5 8 11`

---

If you'd want to print out the even numbers instead, you can:

Start counting from `1`:

```
from itertools import count
sequence = count(start=1, step=1)
while(next(sequence) <= 10):
    print(next(sequence))
```

This will print out `2 4 6 8 10`

Or, if you'd like `0` to be there too, just add a single `print` statement before the `while` loop:

```
from itertools import count
sequence = count(start=0, step=1)
print(next(sequence))
while(next(sequence) <= 10):
    print(next(sequence))
```

This will print out `0 2 4 6 8 10`

---

If you'd want to print each of the numbers, simply persist the output of `next(sequence)`:

```
from itertools import count
sequence = count(start=0, step=1)
element = next(sequence)
while(element <= 10):
    print(element)
    element = next(sequence)
```

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. My mistake was not understanding the initial next() call takes the sequence start value, not stepping through it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start at 1 to get your desired output:

```
sequence = count(start=1, step=1)
while(next(sequence) <= 10):
    print(next(sequence))

2
4
6
8
10
```

Answer (score 0):

this is just a modified version of your code that produce same output
i have added comments as to why the code works in the particular way

```
from itertools import count
sequence = count(start=0, step=1)
# a has value count(0)
a=next(sequence)
while(a <= 10):
    # b has value count(1) 3 5 and so on
    b=next(sequence)
    print(b)
     # a has value count(2) 4 6 and so on
    a=next(sequence)
```